# Tensorflow augmentation layers not working after importing from tf.keras.applications

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently using a model from tf.keras.applications for training. And a data augmentation layer along with it. Wierdly, after I import the model from applications, the augmentation layer does not work. The augmentation layer does work before I import it. What is going on?

Also, this has only started happening recently after the new version of TF 2.8.0 was released. Before it was working all fine.

The code for the augmentation layer is

```
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.5),
])
```

And I am importing the model using

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV3Small(
                 input_shape=(75, 50, 3), alpha=1.0, 
                 weights='imagenet', pooling='avg', include_top=False,
                 dropout_rate=0.1, include_preprocessing=False)
```

Please help me understand what is going on. You can reproduce the code here on this notebook https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13Jd3l2CxbvIWQv3Y7CtryOdrv2IdKNxD?usp=sharing

Comment: Confirmed not working in colab, that is weird...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I noticed same issue with tf 2.8. It can be solved by add training =True , when you **test** the augmentation layer:

```
aug = data_augmentation(image,training=True)
```

The reason is that the augmentation layer behaves differently in training and predicting (inference), i.e. it will do augmentation in training but do nothing in predicting. Ideally, the layer should set the training= argument smartly according the situation. Apparently, it is not smart in above code: it does not know your intention is to test the layer.

But I think you should still leave training argument as default when you build the full  model, letting the augmentation layer do the job.

Comment: This is actually very helpful. When trying to view augmented images before adding the layer to your model, adding training=True allows you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the effect of augmentation from a single output. Please set a range  to see the effect of augmentation.

```
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical",seed=5),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.5),
])
for i in range(4):
  aug = data_augmentation(image)
  plt.imshow(aug.numpy().astype('uint8'))
  plt.show()
```

Comment: ofcourse i tried it multiple times. not working

Comment: This also doesn't work for me. Random flip does not work. Only random cropping works even with training=True.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you
Here is a big correction to do for data augmentation the data is not being augmented. You only have to write

```
`data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical",seed=5),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.5),
])
for i in range(4):
  aug = data_augmentation(image, training = True)
  plt.imshow(aug.numpy().astype('uint8'))
  plt.show()`
```

Now it should work and your images should be augmented.
It is an error and it should be fixed in the next update I think so.